# How does a pkg communicate with the yaml file

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following tutorial how does the package communicate with the yaml file ?

http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/SImple%20URDF-Controller%20Example

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53895/how-does-a-pkg-communicate-with-the-yaml-file/) by [Bharadwaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/4074/bharadwaj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial code is using the [ros parameter server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server).  The parameter server stores different kinds of variables and makes them available to running nodes.

To load a yaml config file onto the parameter server, you'd either load it with the [rosparam load xml tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) in a launch file or use the [rosparam command line program](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1